# Correct pronunciation of "career"

Tags: pronunciation

Is it car-rear? Or, is it carry-er?

The word is very commonly used among Japanese with the same meaning, and we say it like carry-er, which I suppose is wrong.

Comment: I wonder if the Japanese pronunciation is more influenced by the French *carrière* than the English *career*?

Comment: Have you looked up in any dictionary? Dictionaries show pronunciations.

Comment: Yes, Cameron. That's what I thought first. Mehper, sure I did. I just wanted to know if there's another way of saying it in some countries.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Career" vs "carrier"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41106/career-vs-carrier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to represent pronunciation accurately without using phonetic symbols. If it helps, the British non-regional pronunciation is /kəˈrɪə(r)/.

Answer (score 1):

It would be pronounced: Kuh-rear

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible pronunciations, depending on what meaning you are using.

If you mean "an occupation or profession, especially one requiring special training, followed as one's lifework" then the pronunciation is /kɘˈriːɘ/.

If you mean "to run or move rapidly along; go at full speed" then the pronunciation is /kæriːɘ/.

Comment: Thanks! Can anyone else confirm this? Though I would probably never  say it myself as a verb...

Comment: confirm what, knsmr? That it is a verb? Have a look at the entry in [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/career?s=t), item 7.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that the pronunciation is different when used as a verb. Item 7 doesn't say anything about the pronunciation, does it?

Comment: True. It could just be my dialect. I pronounce the verb differently to the noun.

Comment: It makes sense, though. Anyway, I didn't know the verb, so thanks!

Comment: I pronounce them the same.

Comment: I've never heard a different pronunciation for the verb form either; it's always "kuh-Rear".

Comment: What's your dialect then?

Comment: BBC British English I suppose. Perhaps I mean idiolect.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard British pronunciation, *carry-er* and *car-rear* are homophones (assuming the same syllables are stressed). Early in the Libyan war, listening to the BBC news, I couldn't tell whether the city they were talking about was *Zaweer* or *Zawiya,* and I believe U.K. speakers would have the same difficulty. In American English, the pronunciation is definitely *cuh-rear*.

Answer (score 0):

To add my two cents from a BE ear it could be described phonetically as ker-ear